# How to hide a specific row of Excel chart data table?

Tags: excel

So right now I have a chart with 3 series, which will have 3 rows of data in the chart's data table. If I want to hide the last row in the data table, but keep the series in the chart, how can it be done? The only way I can think of is to create a block to cover that part, but is there a better way of doing it?

Edit: I'm looking for a way to show the series in chart, but not in chart data table.

Comment: Besides tossing a white square on the top of the series in the data table (which isn't a terrible option), you could also consider placing the chart above a range in your excel worksheet that points, with formulas, to the actual chart data and hides/shows rows instead of using the chart data table. A transparent background chart area may be a nice feature here too so it looks like the chart envelops the excel range showing the data.

Comment: This superuser post is related and has an additional answer that I found to be very thorough https://superuser.com/q/1658870

Answer (score 1):

Select the last row of chart data and format the cell's displayed text/number as `;;;`. If the chart data is dynamic, then the last row can be identified with something like,

```
=row()=match(1e99, A:A)
```

This would enable you to create a conditional formatting rule that applies the `;;;` cell number format to the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment to your question.

You could:

1. Make a new table on the worksheet that points, via formulas, to the range that the chart is made from.
2. In those formulas, use if() statements to toggle the values on/off based on whatever logic you are using to hide/show. Below I use a checkbox.
3. Remove the data table from your chart
4. Make the background of your chart area "No Fill" so it's transparent.
5. Line your chart x-series up with the formula based table so it looks like the data table for your chart

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I still want to show that series in the chart. I just don't want its data to be shown on the data table.

Comment: I have revised the answer for the different requirements.

Answer (score -2):

You can just make changes in the graphs.

Select the line graph series that you do not want to display in the chart.
Right click and click on "Format Data Series"
Click on "Fill & Line" (an icon of a paint)
Select "No Line"