# Adding trend line in excel charts

Tags: excel, charts, trendline

I have a data series as below

[image]

I need a graph with trend line.

But in excel there is only some standard options available such as 'Moving Average' trend line as below.

[image]

I need something like this and not the average

[image]

So I did the following way. First I duplicated the series as below.

[image]

Then I used a 'Combo' chart type to get as below

[image]

This time I got the same way that I want. But issue is, data table showing duplicate values which I don't want.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025175/how-to-hide-a-specific-row-of-excel-chart-data-table

Comment: Firstly I don't quite understand what is he saying in that post. Second, I am using excel vba to create this chart. So I am not sure if I can apply that in my case. Third, I don't think that post is trying to hide the data table in the chart. Instead it is trying to hide it on the excel sheet

Comment: Why not calculate the "trend values" in a set of cells then plot those results as an extra series formatted appropriately. Then you can use moving sum, moving frequency or 2nd or 3rd order whatever you wish.

Comment: You mean use another series by using a separate table(This data also must be same as current data to get same trend) and add that into the same graph? But even when do that, data table will show that same data again twice.